# How to create a multiple page form using modal on bootstrap

Tags: html, css, user-interface, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I created a page with a table having a list of employees of a company and I implemented a button where if clicked, it has a pop up with a form containing some questions regarding the personal information of a new employee, such as first name, last name, date of birth etc. I want to make the modal as a 3 step form, such as the picture posted below. I want to display this form as a pop up, that's why my first solution was to implement a modal.

[image: 3 step form for new employee]

I already have all the images, such as the circled numbers displayed in the picture, but since I'm a beginner using bootstrap, is there any possible solution way for implementing this 3 step form using modals, or even a more efficient way of implementing this rather than modals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen this https://codepen.io/designify-me/pen/qrJWpG?

```
    <!-- MultiStep Form -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <form id="msform">
            <!-- progressbar -->
            <ul id="progressbar">
                <li class="active">Personal Details</li>
                <li>Social Profiles</li>
                <li>Account Setup</li>
            </ul>
            <!-- fieldsets -->
            <fieldset>
                <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
                <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Tell us something more about you</h3>
                <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name"/>
                <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name"/>
                <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone"/>
                <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next"/>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <h2 class="fs-title">Social Profiles</h2>
                <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your presence on the social network</h3>
                <input type="text" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter"/>
                <input type="text" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook"/>
                <input type="text" name="gplus" placeholder="Google Plus"/>
                <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button-previous" value="Previous"/>
                <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next"/>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
                <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Fill in your credentials</h3>
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
                <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password"/>
                <input type="password" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password"/>
                <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button-previous" value="Previous"/>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit"/>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
        <!-- link to designify.me code snippets -->
        <div class="dme_link">
            <p><a href="http://designify.me/code-snippets-js/" target="_blank">More Code Snippets</a></p>
        </div>
        <!-- /.link to designify.me code snippets -->
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /.MultiStep Form -->
```